# Authentication error 49 52e with jndi in a java application- invalid token

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jndi

I'd like to be ask an LDAP server if the provided username and password are correct in a Java application.

I ended up using jndi with this function (it is a test function I am using to explore LDAP that returns the exception  message):

```
public static String checkCredentials(String securityPrincipal,
                               String password,
                               String ldapUrl,
                               String securityAuthentication) 
{
    String userVerify = "";
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, securityAuthentication);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrincipal);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    try {
        DirContext authContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
        userVerify = testDescription + " - Success";
        authContext.close();
    } catch (AuthenticationException authEx) {
        userVerify = "AuthenticationException: " + authEx.getMessage();//"Authentication failed!";
    } catch (NamingException namEx) {
        userVerify = "NamingException: " + namEx.getMessage();//"Something went wrong!";
    } 
    return userVerify;
}
```

As I call `checkCredentials` by passing the correct `ldapUrl` (that in my case it's `ldap://192.168.48.60:389`) i always get as result (the function returns a  `String`):

> AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr:
>   DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]

This [page](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors) says that  it is an authentication error (49)  and "username is valid but password/credential is invalid" (52e).

I tried all of these for `securityPrincipal`:

> john
>
> john@mycompany
>
> CN=john,conn
>
> CN=john,OU=internal users,DC=mycompany

`password` and `secuirityAuthentication` seem ignored.

I tried to install LDAP admin from http://www.ldapadmin.org/ and also from it I get:

> LDAP error! Invalid credentials: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8,
>   comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1.

Invalid token passed to the function.

Somehow this tells me something more "invalid token".

Any pointers? I  am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing "none" instead of  "simple" in  securityAuthentication made the job.

At least there are no exceptions, even if UserVerifyT returns success even if the passowrd is wrong, i  will handle this as i  did in  the past by retrieving the mail of the user, if mail is returned password is ok.